# Always got empty body from POST req

Tags: go

I'm setting up HTTP server, and want `/test` route to accept POST request, but with this code body is always empty. This is my request body:

```
{
    "asd": "123"
}
```

This is my code:

```golang
func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/test", handleData).Methods("POST")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":80", router))
}

type test1 struct {
    asd string
}

func handleData(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    var test test1
    _ = json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&test)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(test)
}
```

Comment: The `asd` field is *unexported*. Change it to `Asd string \`json:"asd"\``. Identifiers (types, functions, fields, methods, variables, constants, etc.) that start with upper case letter are exported, those that start with lower case are unexported. The json package works only for exported fields, unexported ones are ignored.

Comment: @mkopriva oh god thank you, it's working! Add this as answer so I could mark it as right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `asd` field is *unexported*. Change it to `` Asd string `json:"asd"` ``. Identifiers (types, functions, fields, methods, variables, constants, etc.) that start with upper case letter are exported, those that start with lower case are unexported. The json package works only with exported fields, unexported ones are ignored.